# How to add a control(button) to the outline view of a custom editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an eclipse-plugin which brings its own editor with an outline view.
I already filled the outline view with elements and now I'd like to register actions to some of those elements. If the user (right-)clicks them it should show a popup that behaves like the QuickFix-Popup.

Please help me with some hints or links to related resources or tutorials.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

> post the outline view code

I implemented the view after this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Outline_view_for_my_own_language_editor%3F

It's an outline-view for .jav-files. My .jav-Editor creates the OutlineView which extends `ContentOutlinePage` like this:

```
public Object getAdapter(Class required) {
    if (IContentOutlinePage.class.equals(required)) {
        if (fOutlinePage == null) {
            fOutlinePage= new JavOutline(this.sourceFile);
        }
        return fOutlinePage;
    }

    return super.getAdapter(required);
}
```

The Code of the JavOutline-class:

```
public class JavOutline extends ContentOutlinePage{


private SourceFile syntaxTree;

public JavOutline(SourceFile syntaxTree) {
    this.syntaxTree = syntaxTree;
}


public void createControl(Composite parent) {

    super.createControl(parent);

    TreeViewer viewer = getTreeViewer();
    viewer.setContentProvider(new SyntaxTreeContentProvider());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new SyntaxTreeLabelProvider());
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(this);
    if(this.syntaxTree!=null)viewer.setInput(this.syntaxTree);
}

public void update(SourceFile sourceFile) {
    TreeViewer viewer= getTreeViewer();

    if (viewer != null) {
        Control control= viewer.getControl();
        if (control != null && !control.isDisposed()) {
            control.setRedraw(false);
            viewer.setInput(sourceFile);
            viewer.expandAll();
            control.setRedraw(true);
        }
    }
}

}

class SyntaxTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

public SyntaxTreeContentProvider() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
}

@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    if(! (inputElement instanceof SourceFile))return null;
    return ((SourceFile)inputElement).getChildren().toArray();
}

@Override
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
    if(! (parentElement instanceof SyntaxTreeNode))return null;
    return ((SyntaxTreeNode)parentElement).getChildren().toArray();
}

@Override
public Object getParent(Object element) {
    if(! (element instanceof SyntaxTreeNode))return null;
    return ((SyntaxTreeNode)element).getParent();
}

@Override
public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
    return true;
}
}

class SyntaxTreeLabelProvider extends LabelProvider{

@Override
public String getText(Object element) {
    if(! (element instanceof SyntaxTreeNode))return super.getText(element);
    return ((SyntaxTreeNode)element).getDescription();

}

}
```

I just want call an action when one of the elements in the TreeViewer gets (right-)clicked.

Comment: So have you implemented a `IContentOutlinePage` or what?

Comment: post the outline view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a menu listener for the context menu like this:

```java
final MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager();
menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

menuMgr.addMenuListener(new FillContextMenu());

final Control tree = viewer.getControl();

final Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(tree);

tree.setMenu(menu);


private class FillContextMenu implements IMenuListener
{
  @Override
  public void menuAboutToShow(final IMenuManager manager)
  {
    // TODO add Actions or other items to the menu
  }
}
```